# как передавать путь к файлу?

Tags: c++, fstream

У меня проблема. Мне нужно в мою програму передавать путь к файлу, который нужно считать. Я передаю так -

```
 "D\:Proga\File\file.txt"
```

Но это захардкоджено.А мне нужно чтобы  оно открывалось и на  другом компе. Как сделать глобальный путь. Как изменить чтобы это не писать -

```
D\:
```

Comment: Использовать относительные пути, [переменные окружения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B_Windows) и выносить в конфиги.

Comment: @free_ze наведите пример, если не сложно

Comment: `%SYSTEMDRIVE%` -> `D:` (в вашем случае)

Comment: Передавайте путь к файлу в командной строке, в чем проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать относительный путь, например так:

```
std::string path("\\File\\file.txt");
```

Если программа лежит в папке "D:Proga\Bin", то надо выйти на уровень вверх:

```
std::string path("..\\File\\file.txt");
```

(Двойная косая черта нужна, так как в Си одинарная такая черта обозначает управляющий символ).

Вариант, как могла бы выглядеть ваша программа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        std::string path(argv[1]);
        std::ofstream fout(path);
        // Тут работаем с файлом
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Enter path to file!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Запуск:

> a.exe ..\File\file.txt